# Putting images into a dataframe to be exported as Excel

Tags: python, excel, dataframe, selenium

I am currently trying to take screenshots of a list of URLs/web pages, then to put them into a dataframe, to then be exported as an excel document. Right now, I have the following code, which successfully takes screenshots of the list of URLs and saves them as pngs:

```
driver.maximize_window()

for index, url in enumerate(testurl):
    try:
        driver.get(url)
        sleep(3)
        driver.get_screenshot_as_file('screenshot' + str(index) + '.png')
        
    except:
        print(testurl[index] + ' took too long')
```

However, is it now possible to somehow get these screenshots into a python Dataframe, to be exported as an excel document? e.g.

[Example of how I want it to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywnWU.png)

Not sure how to go about this -- any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You can create Excel documents with images easily using `XlsxWriter` package. You can see an example here (code is at the bottom of the page): https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_images.html